# Variable between php files

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli, database-connection

Before anyone points out my code is flawed in security or etc know that I am quite a PHP noob and wouldn't mind you forwarding some help to fix that rather than just yelling it is terrible.

Also I did try this below and it won't work for me because it stores it into the session (Unless session is more secure than I thought. I assume users can extract data from one, correct?):
http://tinyurl.com/myqx3xo

As for my question, how would I be able to access the variable $connectdb in my users function? When I do that it gives me 'Undefined variable' error, and isn't detecting that it exists whatsoever. Both are requires in `main\folder\start.php` that is loaded every page, and on those pages I attempted to call the function and it gave me a failure. The code works fine when I attempt to hardcode the $connectdb's varible into the functions but again there are good reasons not to. Will add additional details if required.

Undefined variable: connectdb in main\folder\folder1\users.php on the line that starts with $data

**main\folder\folder1\users.php function:**

```
function user_data($id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '' . implode(', ', $func_get_args) . '';
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connectdb,"SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE id = $id"));
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**main\folder\folder2\connect.php:**

```
<?php
$connect_fail = 'Example connection failure.';

$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$db     = 'database';
$connectdb = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die($connect_fail);
?>
```

Comment: are you include connect.php into your  users.php file

Comment: No? I think I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: include("connect.php") file than try.

Answer (score 1):

include your connect.php into your user.php

```
include('../fodler2/connect.php');

function user_data($id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '' . implode(', ', $func_get_args) . '';
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connectdb,"SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE id = $id"));
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: include(../folder2/connect.php): failed to open stream. Happens when I attempt that... :(

Answer (score 0):

in your users.php file you need to add

```
include "../folder2/connect.php";
```